# How to break FileList for loop Angular 16 in HttpClient Observable

Tags: angular, loops, observable, break

I need break FileList FOR loop in error case in HttpClient Observable. I make a request with post method for upload 1 file for each loop iteration. This is my code, but not working, not breaking loop.

```
        let error = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
          const file = this.files.item(i)!;
          this.httpService.importReport(this.report, file, this.code).subscribe({
            error: e => {
              this.httpService.showError(e);
              error = true;
            },
            next: event => {
              const type = event.type;
              if (type==HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
                const total = event.total!;
                const loaded = event.loaded!;
                this.uploadProgress = loaded / total;
              } else if (type == HttpEventType.Response) {
                console.log(event.body);
              }
            },
            complete: () => {
              this.uploadProgress = 0;
              this.uploadedFiles++;
            }
          });
          if (error) break;
        }
```

I tried try/catch clause with pipes concatMap and catchError with throwError but it doesn't work.

Comment: The code inside subscription is an async code. Hence when you are checking the if(error) the subscription code may not have completed its execution which is resulting in the error value to remain false. Either you need to use aync await for synchronous execution of code or come up with some other solution

Comment: Do you know any alternative to upload files with FOR loop?

Comment: If server side is under your control why not send the entire array in one shot. If you are using node that should be pretty straight forward? Or as user is uploading each file you can send them to server without waiting for all the files. But if this is the approach you want to follow I guess synchronous call is your best bet

Comment: Use something like https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat

Answer (score 0):

I already found a definitive solution without FOR loop.

```
async import(file?: File) {
    if (this.files && this.files.length>0) {
      this.uploadedFiles = 0;
      this.loading = true;
      if(!file) file = this.files.item(0)!;
      this.httpService.importReport(this.report, file, this.code).subscribe({
        error: e => {
          this.httpService.showError(e);
          this.files = undefined;
          this.label = 'Ningún archivo seleccionado';
          this.loading = false;
          this.uploadProgress = -1;
          this.error = `File <strong>&laquo; ${file!.name} &raquo;</strong> has an error.`;
        },
        next: event => {
          const type = event.type;
          if (type==HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            const total = event.total!;
            const loaded = event.loaded!;
            this.uploadProgress = (loaded / total)*100;
          } else if (type == HttpEventType.Response) {
            console.log(event.body);
          }
        },
        complete: async () => {
          this.okFilenames.push(file!.name);
          this.uploadProgress = -1;
          this.uploadedFiles++;
          if (this.uploadedFiles==this.files!.length) {
            this.loading = false;
            this.message = `¡${this.files!.length} files imported successfully!`;
            this.emitter.emit();
            setTimeout(() => this.modal.dismiss('Cross Click'), 2000);
          } else {
            if (this.report=='teachers') await this.sleep(1000);
            await this.import(this.files!.item(this.uploadedFiles)!);
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.error = 'Please, select at least 1 file.';
      setTimeout(() => {this.error = '';}, 1500);
    }
  }
```